# How to set status of checkbox to checked on AngularJS belong to the value in array

Tags: checkbox, angular5

I have the array of product options that 1 option has been set as a default option. I set it by set the value as 1 for the picked option and 0 for another elements.

```
<div class="attribute-set" *ngFor="let attr of optionAttrArray; index as i;"><input type="checkbox" name="default" id="option-{{optionAttrArray[i].attribute_id}}" [value]="optionAttrArray[i].set_default" (change)="changeDetault(i)"/></div>
```

TS file below:

```
addNewAttribute(){
    this.optionAttrArray.push({
        attribute_id: "0",
        name: '',
        price: '',
        sku: '',
        status: "1",
        set_default:"0",
    });
}
```

`set_default = 0` mean not picked, 1 mean set as default option

I need to make the checkbox status checked if set_default = 1 when click to edit this attribute group

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help in asking.

Comment: Please include actual code with your question. I highly recommend reading both "[ask]" and "[mcve]", before [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've founded the solution by myself. It just the property of the checkbox like this

```
[checked]="optionAttrArray[i].set_default == 1"
```